# How to make a python program to monitor my browser downloads based on the origin URL?

Tags: python, browser, automation, download

I've started learning Python and would like to take this challenge but I don't know where to start.

I'd like for it work like this: a image downloaded from Pinterest is save to a folder of the same name.

I tried looking for similar question on stack.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Project-wide questions are offtopic here.  You need to have a specific programming question.  If you're starting on python, try searching for tutorials on the net, particularly on parts of the program you're trying to make.  Then put it together or ask here on a specific issue.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "download"?  Every single image you see in your browser was **downloaded**, in some sense of the word.  Do you mean "saved in my Downloads folder"?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the `watchdog` package. Knowing the origin is a bit more difficult, maybe you can make a browser plugin? This example can monitor a specific directory on your computer though, which might be half of what you're trying to do.

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

class DownloadHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        print(f'File {event.src_path} has been downloaded')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    event_handler = DownloadHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path='/path/to/download/directory', recursive=False)
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()

    observer.join()
```